# AngularJS 1: How not to "Socket hang up" on a request which is taking long time to respond

Tags: angularjs, sockets

I am sending a request from client(angularjs) to backend requesting 1million records. I know this is dumb but that's the requirement. The request will run a stored procedure in Oracle database which is taking around 3 minutes and within this time, at the client side, am getting the error "problem with request: socket hang up" and the request is failed.

Can anyone please let me know how to increase this time taken for socket to hangup ? or any other solution is also welcome

Thanks in advance.